# Golang HTML Template Nested Range Loop

Tags: html, go, go-templates

```golang
type Info struct {
    ID           int      `json:"id"`
    RevCusRat    []string `json:"revcusrat"`
    RevCusCom    []string `json:"revcuscom"`
}
```

I made a template below, the data is coming, but I need to nest the range loop.

```golang
{{ range $revCom := .RevCusCom}}
      <div class="col-12">
          <textarea> {{$revCom}} </textarea>
      </div>
{{end}}
                
{{ range $revRtg := .RevCusRat}}
      <div class="col-3">
          <textarea> {{$revRtg}} </textarea>
      </div>
{{end}}
```

Can I make it like this? (I tried but does not work. how can I do this in different ways?) I want one comment and one rating to come in order on HTML page.

```
{{ range $revCom := .RevCusCom}}
     {{ range $revRtg := .RevCusRat}}
         <div class="col-12">
            <textarea> {{$revCom}} </textarea>
            <textarea> {{$revRtg}} </textarea>
         </div>
      {{end}}
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are doing it, you'll print all `revRtg` for each `revCom`. If that's really what you need to do:

```
{{ range $revRtg := $.RevCusRat}}
```

so you can access the `.RevCusRat` in the outer scope.

However, if you want to print the `revRgt` matching the `revCom`:

```
{{ range $index,$revCom := .RevCusCom}}
    <div class="col-12">
        <textarea> {{$revCom}} </textarea>
        <textarea> {{index $.RevCusRat $index}} </textarea>
    </div>
{{end}}
```

Comment: that worked. just need extra {{end}} tag --> {{ range $revRtg := $.RevCusRat}} {{end}}